# Historical Records of Noahidism

Tags: gentiles, noahidism

Are there any pre-Talmudic recordings of the teachings of the 7 Noahide Laws?

I understand all 7 are found in Genesis but what is the earliest record of a structured idea of these 7 being necessary for gentiles?

Answer (score 2):

The Tosefta is a compilation of the Jewish oral law from the late 2nd century, the period of the Mishnah. Tosefta [Avoda Zara 9:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Avodah_Zarah.9.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) describes six of the seven Noahide laws

> על שבע מצות נצטוו בני נח על הדינין ועל עבודת כוכבים ועל גלוי עריות ועל
>   שפיכות דמים ועל הגזל ועל אבר מן החי

The gemara in [Sanhedrin 56a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.56a.24?lang=bi&with=Tosefta%20Avodah%20Zarah&lang2=en) quotes this Tosefta (but lists seven, adding the prohibition to curse the name of God), then proceeds to add to them and to source their origin in Bereshit (translation: R Steinsaltz)

> Since the halakhot of the descendants of Noah have been mentioned, a
>   full discussion of the Noahide mitzvot is presented. The Sages taught
>   in a baraita: The descendants of Noah, i.e., all of humanity, were
>   commanded to observe seven mitzvot: The mitzva of establishing courts
>   of judgment; and the prohibition against blessing, i.e., cursing, the
>   name of God; and the prohibition of idol worship; and the prohibition
>   against forbidden sexual relations; and the prohibition of bloodshed;
>   and the prohibition of robbery; and the prohibition against eating a
>   limb from a living animal.

So I think the Tosefta above is the first source in pre-Talmudic material.

Comment: Are there any earlier examples of this structured understanding that the 7 should be followed?

Comment: @charlesS I gave you the earliest source I know of. But there is not a lot of pre-Mishnaic halakhic material